# Form inside dialog in Primefaces or form containing dialogs

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I wanted to know what is the best practice with form elements when implementing a dialog in Primefaces.

In detail, in my implementation i have two approaches for dialogs.

1. In my pages i have a main form which contains all components (textfields, etc.) . Dialogs  are out of the main form. Those dialogs have their own form inside.
2. In my pages i have a main form which contains all components including dialogs. Of course those dialogs do not have their on form.

Both scenarios work well. I wanted to know if there is any reason to prefer any of those two approaches. Using of course the 1st approach, we can easily reuse those dialogs.

Comment: Some answers from the provided questions were helpful. Thank you !

Comment: Try selecting the most upvoted jsf questions and read all that have more than 20. You'll learn a lot